# using Ansible with VMware ESXi Server

Tags: ansible, vmware, esxi

I want to automate VM creation on ESXi server from Ansible. I am supposed to install pysphere module on VMWare ESXi Server. But this server does not use apt, yum or easy-install. Even if I try to use shell commands, I get errors related to dependencies on ESXi server. Is there any workaround available for this?

Answer (score 2):

> I am supposed to install pysphere module on VMWare ESXi Server

Why do you think so?

Usually you call VM provisioning modules like `vsphere_guest` from your Ansible control host (localhost), so pysphere should be installed on your localhost and not on ESXi server.

Example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
      vcenter_hostname: vcenter.mydomain.local
      username: myuser
      password: mypass
      guest: newvm001
      state: absent
      force: yes
```